# hub.statechange disconnects when changing page

Tags: signalr

So I'm having a display issue and was wondering the best way to solve it. When the $.connection.hub.stateChanged event fires and it is in the disconnected state I display a dialog to the user saying connection lost. 
But unfortunately when I change page this event is fired and displays the dialog before the page changes, displaying this error for a few seconds.

Is the best way to disable the statechange event when I navigate to a different button? Or can i do somecheck in the event something like:

```
$.connection.hub.stateChanged(function (change) {
    if (change.newState === $.connection.connectionState.disconnected) {
        //Pseudo code:
        if (!pageIsChanging) {
            $('#lostConnectivityDiv').modal('show');
        }
    }
});
```

or is there a jquery event for when the page change event is fired before the hub will be disconnected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your trying to notify the user that the connection has been lost a better route would be to tie into the reconnecting state (*B* below).

See the answer to: [When does a reconnect in signalR occour?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455916/when-does-a-reconnect-in-signalr-occour/14465876) for background.

**A)**
For SignalR there's only one point in which a true connection loss occurs, **#4** in the link above.  When I say true connection loss I mean the point in which the SignalR connection stops attempting to reconnect.

**B)**
However, depending on how you want to implement your notification you could also argue that it should only be triggered on reconnecting (meaning the network is down but the connection is trying to recover).

All that being said you can implement your notification either way.

*Implementation for A:*

```
var tryingToReconnect = false;

$.connection.hub.reconnecting(function() {
    tryingToReconnect = true;
});

$.connection.hub.reconnected(function() {
    tryingToReconnect = false;
});

$.connection.hub.disconnected(function() {
    if(tryingToReconnect) {
        notifyUserOfDisconnect(); // Your function to notify user
    }
});
```

*Implementation for B:*

```
$.connection.hub.reconnecting(function() {
    notifyUserOfDisconnect(); // Your function to notify user
});
```