# Is it possible that OnDisconnected event will be fired even though connection is not closed on SignalR SelfHost server?

Tags: c#, signalr, self-hosting

We created a self-host `SignalR` server and our WPF Desktop application is connecting to that server. We are just doing login-logout management, everything is simple and working. But after sometime, usually 2-3 hours, half of the client are disappearing from online clients list.

It appears that, `OnDisconnected` event is triggered on server for connections, even though they are not closed. After `OnDisconnected` event, these connections can still send and receive data.

Is there any scenario that causes to `OnDisconnected` event triggered on server when connection is not closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any scenario that causes to OnDisconnected event triggered on
>   server when connection is not closed?

Yes. If connection is timed out, first disconnect then reconnect occurs (if the client don't close the connection explicitly).

> ```
> public override System.Threading.Tasks.Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
> {
>     if (stopCalled)
>     {
>         Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Client {0} explicitly closed the connection.", Context.ConnectionId));
>     }
>     else
>     {
>         Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Client {0} timed out .", Context.ConnectionId));
>     }
>
>     return base.OnDisconnected();
> }
> ```

As you can see here. If explicitly disconnect occurs (`stopCalled` is true), client is disconnected for sure and reconnect will not occur.

if client is really not disconnected, after disconnect reconnect can occur like in your stuation.

Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14465876/3432471) fore more detail

Comment: Thank you for the answer, we didn't do any control on OnReconnected event, that was the problem i guess.

Comment: please check uniqueness of connection Id (If you keep them) on Reconnected. Iif reconnect occurs without disconnect occurs you may ,have duplicate records. Check here http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections